# Programmatically determine Coherence master member

Tags: java, oracle-coherence

I need to **run a piece of my java code by only one `Coherence` cluster member**. So, I chose the master member for this. Is there an API to check out whether the current member is the master coordinator member? I am using `Oracle Coherence 12.1.3-0-0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NamedCache cache = CacheFactory.getCache("cacheName");
Cluster c = cache.getCacheService().getCluster();
if (c.getLocalMember().equals(c.getOldestMember())) {
  //do the stuff
}
```